# Apache: Tomcat doesn't start automatically; can't be uninstall either

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, xampp

I've installed the latest versions of XAMPP. When I run the Control Panel and try to start services, while Apache and MySQL start successfully, I get problems with Tomcat. It can't be started using the button "Start" - it just writes `Attempting to start Tomcat service..` and it never ends. I can start Tomcat manually, by opening `catalina_start.bat`; the same approach is used when I need to stop Tomcat.

I thought maybe uninstalling and installing again Tomcat as service might help, but it appears I can't do that either. When I try to do it I get `Service was NOT (un)installed!` red message.

What is this all about and what can I do about it?

Comment: can it be that on the ports that tomcat needs you have another application that uses them?

Comment: @Edwin, Then the `catalina_start.bat` wouldn't work too, would it?